# gwt-dev - Librairies with same package name

Tags: java, gwt, maven-2, apache-commons

This is my first post on stackoverflow, please be indulgent.

Within my project, I use the library `commons-digester-1.8`.
Following a need, I now use the library `gwt-dev-2.3.0`.

When launching the application I get this error :

```
Exception caught while initializing context java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org/apache/commons/digester/xmlrules/DigesterLoader.createDigester(Lorg/xml/sax/InputSource;)Lorg/apache/commons/digester/Digester;
    at fr.cnasea.commons.webfwk.util.config.lecture.XMLDigesterReader.getConfig(XMLDigesterReader.java:157)
    at fr.cnasea.commons.webfwk.util.config.CnaseaAppConfigurator.configure(CnaseaAppConfigurator.java:76)
    at fr.cnasea.osiris.commons.gwt.server.Config.contextInitialized(Config.java:47)
```

It turns out that the two libraries have the same class in the same package with the same method:

[Same class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sGLHL.png)

Since the use of gwt-dev, it is the method of this library which is called.
I tried to use newer versions of gwt-dev but the environment makes it not possible

How can I fix it?

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: What is your setup in maven? How are the dependencies declared? Also can you post the full stacktrace? One thing you could try is to remove the commons-digester-1.8 dependency from the build since it appears to have the same class. It is possible the runtime is picking up the class where the method is missing. Or maybe code in your project is calling the missing method and needs updated to use the new version of the class.

Comment: Uuuuh ... gwt 2.3.0 was released May2, 2011 ...

Answer (score 3):

(From my answer to your [same question on the github project](https://github.com/gwtproject/gwt/issues/9685))

The gwt-dev.jar should not be on your server classpath - it is only used to compile your application. The same is true for gwt-user.jar. Only gwt-servlet.jar (and possibly requestfactory-server.jar) should end up on your server classpath, the others are intended only to be present when compiling, either to do the work of compiling, or to provide the compiler the classes you need.